# Angular2 & Typescript - Create object from nested JSON

Tags: json, angular, inheritance, typescript

I have a class which has multiple interfaces inside of it to model a JSON data. For example:

```
interface A {
   id: number;
}

interface B {
   name: string;
   surname?: string;
}

class MyClass implements A {
  people: B[];
  notes: string[];

  function1(){...}
  function2(){...}
}
```

And I have a JSON in the same structure:

```
{
  id: 1,
  people: [
    {
      name: "john"
    },
    {
      name: "alice",
      surname: "smith"
    }
  ],
  notes: [ "Very important top secret note" ]
}
```

Can I create an instance of `MyClass` from this JSON directly?

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure is almost the same as your class, you'd have to add an id property to the class

```
class MyClass implements A {
    id: number;
    // ....
}
```

The problem is if you were trying to do something like this:

```
let data: MyClass = {
  id: 1,
  people: [
    {
      name: "john"
    },
    {
      name: "alice",
      surname: "smith"
    }
  ],
  notes: [ "Very important top secret note" ]
}
```

This won't work because your json does not have the methods (function1, function2).

One solution would be to really instantiate the MyClass and pass the json, or have a constructor method for that like

```
class MyClass {
    static createFrom(jsonData: A & B): MyClass {
       // create the objct and return
    }
}
```

Or, you could create a variable of that type by combining an existing instance of the class and spreading the json.

Like so:

```
let json = {
    id: 1,
    people: [
        {
            name: "john"
        },
        {
            name: "alice",
            surname: "smith"
        }
    ],
    notes: ["Very important top secret note"]
}
const c = new MyClass();

let mClass: MyClass = {...json, function1: c.function1, function2: c.function2 };

mClass.function1();
```

[Link to playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20surname%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%20implements%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20people%3A%20B%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20notes%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function1()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.id)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20function2()%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20json%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20people%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22john%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22alice%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20surname%3A%20%22smith%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20notes%3A%20%5B%22Very%20important%20top%20secret%20note%22%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20c%20%3D%20new%20MyClass()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20mClass%3A%20MyClass%20%3D%20%7B...json%2C%20function1%3A%20c.function1%2C%20function2%3A%20c.function2%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AmClass.function1()%3B)

Comment: First of all, A interface has the `id` field and `MyClass` implements it, should I declare it again? Secondly, I have much more interfaces/classes than this example, so initiating all of them with a constructor that takes json will take too much time. Lastly, I tried to create an instance of a class that have no methods as `a: AClass = { ... }` but when I did that, `a instance of AClass` returned false. Is the second method you suggested create a real instance of this class or is it just keeping it as `json`?